# An algorithm from the Jean Meeus book

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry, pascal, astronomy

I am writing a simple program to calculate the phases of the moon; I use the algorithms presented in Jean Meeus' book "Astronomical algorithms" 2nd edition.

On p. 350 (chapter 49) he writes:

> Calculate [...] the following angles, which are expressed in *degrees* and may be reduced
> to the interval 0-360 degrees and, if necessary, to radians before going further on

So the conversion should look like this:

1. reduction of the angle to the range 0-360
2. conversion of the angle from degrees to radians

Next, on page 353, he gives a series of examples:

> M = -8234.2625 = 45.7375
>
> M1 = -108984.6278 = 95.3722

But I don't understand how the conversions were made. I have tried the following calculations (in pascal-like) for the value `M`

```pascal
// 1. reduction of the angle to the range 0-360
deg := -8234.2625;
reducedDeg := Abs(deg mod 360) // 314.2625

// 2. conversion of the angle from degrees to radians
convertedDeg := reducedDeg * Pi / 180 // 5.4849
```

So the result of the conversion is 5.4849 while the expected result should be 45.7375.
Same thing for the second example `M1`:

```pascal
// 1. reduction of the angle to the range 0-360
deg: = -108984.6278;
reducedDeg := Abs(deg mod 360); // 264.6278;

// 2. conversion of the angle from degrees to radians
convertedDeg := reducedDeg * Pi / 180; // 4,6186 should be 95.3722
```

What could be the problem?

---

### For clarity:

`Abs(val mod x)` in those examples is the positive (absolute) remainder of dividing `val` by `x`; is an abbreviation for the following sequence:

```pascal
// reduction of the angle to the range 0-360 => Abs(-8234.2625 mod 360)
val := -8234.2625;
val := val / 360; // −22.872951389
If (val < 0) // in the range 0-360 there are only positive numbers
begin
  val := val * -1; // 22.872951389
end
val := val - Int(val); // 0.872951389
val := val * 360; // 314.2625
```

Comment: (1) The results in the book are in degrees. You are comparing degrees to radians. (2) You are not dealing with negative angles correctly. Why are you taking the absolute value? It is totally wrong.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: it is not totally wrong, it is useless. The result of mod 360 is always a non-negative number.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: no, (-1°) mod 360° = 359° and |359°| = 359°. Nothing wrong.

Comment: Oh yes I thought OP takes the abs value of the argument. My bad

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: in fact, the `mod` operator used by the OP does take the absolute value of the argument, which is wrong, but the OP couldn't know.

Comment: To make the negative angle number positive, divide its absolute value by 360, round up to the next integer and add it multiplied by 360 again.

Comment: @Sebastian: you probably mean to the previous integer. By the way, many truncation functions do not implement a true floor operation for negatives, and the problem remains.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I wrote *its absolute value*, so it is the next integer and the ceil (now not floor) operation would work on a positive number. E.g. Abs(-540) / 360 = 1.5. Round up to 2. Multiply by 360 = 720. Add -540 + 720 = 180.

Comment: @Sebastian: sorry, I understood "to compute the correct modulo".

Comment: @YvesDaoust The way shown in my comment does compute the correct modulo for negative arguments.

Comment: @AkiraTakeshi Your clarification is not true for Pascal mod and your clarification is not consistent with Meeus method and not suitable for angles. The Pascal Mod function returns a negative result for negative input. Add 360 to its negative result instead of taking the absolute value or multiplying by -1. Use a calculator and take the sin function. sin -30° = sin 330° ≠ sin 30°. 330° is the correct result. Or think of angles around a circle, which angle lies on which one.

Comment: @Sebastian I know my procedure is incorrect, otherwise I wouldn't have asked a question here. What is the mistake? What is the correct procedure? Can you add two lines of code to the answer as well? Thank you.

Comment: reducedDeg := deg mod 360; IF (reducedDeg < 0) reducedDeg := reducedDeg + 360;

Comment: or easier `reducedDeg := ((deg mod 360) + 360) mod 360;`

Comment: @AloisChristen Then for a one-liner I would prefer `reducedDeg := 180 - Sign(deg) * 180 + deg mod 360;` Less divisions. Perhaps faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your “`mod`” algorithm (reduce angle to [0.0°, 360°) range) is wrong, in particular:

> ```
> If (val < 0) // in the range 0-360 there are only positive numbers
> begin
>   val := val * -1; // 22.872951389
> end
> ```

This will *mirror*, “flip” the angle along the x-axis.
You do not want to do that.
What you meant to do is

```pascal
val := val + ord(val < 0) * 360; { conditionally add a complete turn }
```

---

You can avoid all of this troubles if you have a compiler complying to the ISO standard 10206, “Extended Pascal”.
You can then solve this sub‑task using the built‑in data type `complex`:

```pascal
program degreeToRadianDemo(output);
const
    { This is meant to familiarize you with the functions. }
                pi = 2 * arg(cmplx(0.0, maxReal));
    { 1° ≘ π / 180 rad }
    degreeInRadian = pi / 180;
var
    degree, radian: real;
begin
    degree := -108984.6278;
    
    { `arg` returns principal argument, i. e. `real` in (−π, +π] }
    radian := arg(polar(maxReal, degree * degreeInRadian));
    { Add one turn (2π) if we’re in the (−π, 0.0) range. }
    radian := radian + ord(radian < 0.0) * 2 * pi;
    
    writeLn(                 radian:8:4);
    { Convert back to degrees. }
    writeLn(radian / degreeInRadian:8:4);
end.
```

This works with the GPC (GNU Pascal Compiler).
The FPC (FreePascal Compiler) furnishes a `ucomplex` `unit`, but it only supports a rectangular `complex` (i. e. there is no `arg` and `polar`).
[FPC version 3.2.0]

---

Furthermore – I know this is meant to be an exercise for you – but don’t program what’s already been programmed for you.
Delphi and the FPC deliver a [`math` unit](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/rtl/math/index.html).
This `unit` has the `DegToRad` and `RadToDeg` functions.
There is also a `FMod` function – `mod` operator for `real` numbers – and `mod` operator overload, because using the `DegToRad`/`RadToDeg` functions you will still need to eliminate *complete* turns.
Have a look at [`FMod`’s implementation](https://gitlab.com/freepascal.org/fpc/source/-/blob/release_3_2_0/rtl/objpas/math.pp#L2475-L2504).

---

Since there seems to have been some confusion regarding the `mod` operator, a quote from the ISO standard 7185 (“Standard Pascal”), page 48:

> A term of the form `i mod j` shall be an error if `j` is zero or negative;
> otherwise, the value of `i mod j` shall be that value of `(i − (k × j))` for integral `k` such that `0 ≤ i mod j < j`.

Thus the result of the `mod` operator is *guaranteed to be non-negative*.
Unfortunately, though, not all compilers adhere to the ISO standards.
For instance, in the FPC (FreePascal Compiler) will only return the proper result if `{$modeSwitch isoMod+}` is set.
Rest assured, however, Delphi and the GPC (GNU Pascal Compiler) do work correctly.

Comment: Nice enough and interesting. The specific solution with complex numbers seems to be the same as with mod, at least it avoids no troubles, as a full turn has to be conditionally added nevertheless.

Comment: @Sebastian Well, it saves you the troubles of devising a `mod` algorithm. [`Arg` can be computed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part) with [Atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). Evaluation of this function does not require some kind of `mod`.

Comment: The `mod` continues to be called in the `polar` or the complex or trigonometric functions it calls in turn. Especially for large arguments, trigonometric functions have to calculate the `mod` of the argument modulo `2 pi`.